# In Vim, LaTeX inline equation completion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, latex, equation, omnicomplete

That's Vim gives us a list of matched "$ some maths symbles $" when we press some keys after typing just "$" or "$ with more maths".

Comment: Your question is too general and too specific at the same time. Anyway, have you tried using vim latex suite? It might provide some of the functionalities you're looking for...

Comment: @Nigu, thanks for your comment, i will make it more general. (I'm using latex-box. It seems latex-suite does not have such completion neither.)

Comment: No, don't understand me wrong. Stackexchange actually wants specific questions. Which in your case is. My bad choice of words. What I meant when saying it is too general, is that what you want to achieve is too general to be reasonably possible with such plugins. When you use latex-suite, it always puts both opening and closing brackets at the same time, so you wont encounter such issue.  I don't know for latex-box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [solution](https://github.com/ying17zi/LaTeX-Box) (basing on latex-box) for completing inline eqs in either **inline env** or **numbered env**

That's you have typed two eqs, you want to type them for another time:

```
% two inline eqs
$hello$  $world$

% completion in inline env
$[part of "hello"]<ctrl-x><ctrl-o>

% completion in numbered env, 
% it's still triggered in the same way, but will leave eq without "$"
\begin{equation}
    $[part of "world"]<ctrl-x><ctrl-o>
```

**EDIT1**

In the [official repo](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box) of Latex-box, this functionality is disabled by default.

The switch is `let g:LatexBox_complete_inlineMath = 1`.